# What is the cardinality of the set of shapes?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Consider the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. A figure is a subset of the Euclidean plane. Two figures $S$ and $T$ are said to have the same shape iff there is a composition of an isometry and a dilation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the image of $S$ is $T$. It is easy to prove that "having the same shape" is an equivalence relation on the set of figures. I define a shape to be an equivalence class of that equivalence relation. My question is, what is the cardinality of the set of shapes? I conjecture that it is $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. Is this true, and if so, what is the proof?

Comment: Just checking that those really are the conditions you require a "figure" to have - no conditions like "is a closed curve" or anything that would make it look like, well, a shape?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite the geometric flavor, this is really a cardinal arithmetic question. Each equivalence class has size at most continuum (since that's how many isometries and dilations there are), and whenever we partition a set of size $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ (such as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)$) into size-$\le 2^{\aleph_0}$ classes we always wind up with $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$-many classes.

Note that this is very coarse - the result wouldn't change if, for example, we allowed **arbitrary** continuous self-bijections of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the definition of shape.

On the other hand, things get (a bit) more interesting if you restrict attention to "nice" shapes. For example, if we only look at *closed* sets in the plane, then we're partitioning a set of size $2^{\aleph_0}$ into equivalence classes each of which has size $\le 2^{\aleph_0}$, and at that point any number of classes between $1$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$ inclusive is "cardinal-theoretically" possible; we have to actually think about the geometry to get that there are still as many shapes as there could be.